How to remove sheet laminate backsplash from wall?
I am renovating (see: gutting to an empty room and utterly rebuilding) my 1950s kitchen.  As far as I can tell, it's never been done - there was a coat of paint at some point, but it looks as though the cabinets are all built in place.  The countertops were OBS with sheet laminate, which curved at the back and was glued to the wall, too, as a backsplash.
I've removed some by force, but the glue is actually holding pretty well in most places.  Can anybody identify what glue might have been used?  I'm looking for the lowest-effort way of getting it off the wall, with a fallback of "40 grit sandpaper to oblivion," but I'd rather avoid that because there's quite a lot - probably some ~15-20 square feet of this.


Well, given that it appears to be a black mastic, step zero (particularly before pulling out the 40 grit) is the asbestos test to determine if it's "THAT" sort of black mastic.

@Ecnerwal It... probably is.  There's other stuff in the attic (which will be exposed when I remove the soffit here) that I'm treating as asbestos-containing already, so I'm wearing a mask and I've sealed the room.  Appreciate the pointer, though!

Hard to say from afar, but I think the black you’re seeing is intrinsic to the formica, not asbestos-y mastic. Agree that a flameless heat gun is the way.

And to be pedantic, the substrate for the counter is particle board. Oriented strand board has bigger flakes. /pedant

@AloysiusDefenestrate I'm relatively familiar with particle vs OSB, and in this case it was OSB or another plywood, not an MDF or particleboard.  It was in bad shape, but I think it would have totally disintegrated by now were it not something a bit tougher.

You might try, carefully (and with a nice big fire extinguisher handy) heat to soften the adhesive so it can be scraped off with a puttyknife or similar. Preferably a flameless heat gun, (or some sort of steam heater?) and even then be careful to avoid overheating and ignition.
Or  simply (it's messy, yes, but it actually is simpler) remove the drywall and laminate as one, and replace that section of drywall. Drywall is cheap and fast to replace.

I'll give it a shot with steam, I think.  After I try - or after a couple more days - I'll come back to accept an answer.  Thanks!

Not sure steam is warm enough for adhesive softening, so don’t give up if it doesn’t work.
